# React setState: are multiple callbacks synchronized?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, synchronization, concurrentmodification

Say there is such a case:
In the state, there is a list, which corresponding to multiple rows in a table on the UI. There are multiple api calls, one for each item (row), which will retrieve the latest status, and update one item in the list.

In such case, I can understand that callback method will be better than direct call of setState. However, I still don't know whether multiple calls of the callback will be synchronized. 
For example, whether the following situation will happen?

1. callback 1 reads list
2. callback 2 reads list
3. callback 1 updates list(0)
4. callback 2 updates list(1)
5. callback 1 writes back
6. callback 2 writes back

In such case, the update from 1 might be lost, which is typical for read-modify-write.

Comment: You can concat the previous state

Answer (score 0):

I still do not clearly understand your problem, perhaps if you could provide some code it would be better.

But if you meant to call a fetch function multiple times and setting the state once it's arrived, then you should be safe to assume that a setState should not override another, whether were your calls done asynchronously or synchronously.

But in any case, you shouldn't as a front-end send this much requests at once, you should request all the data from the server

Comment: Thank you, I have to update each individual one, since it is a third party service. The issue is that, I am updating one item nested in a list, but when I set state, it is setting the whole list. Therefore, update two above might not know update 1 already happened, and will overwrite the value update 1 just did.